# Will Parallel.Foreach block until it is done?

Tags: c#, asp.net

If I have code similar to this:

```
foreach (Item child in item.Children)
{
     // Do stuff
     ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions();
     options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3;
     Parallel.ForEach(items, i => DoStuff());
}
```

Is the Parallel.Foreach going to finish all of its items before moving on to the next foreach item?

Comment: Parallel.Foreach only runs its iterations in parallel using several threads. It should block until all iterations are done.

Comment: My half-asleep mind though this was a question about Will Ferrell spelled incorrectly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes - Parallel.ForEach will block.   It's a synchronous method, which internally does its work in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

I've gone with a slightly bizarre way to demonstrate the desired property below, because I can't find any nice excerpts from the documentation for e.g. `Parallel.ForEach` that just come out and states that the loops are completed before the methods return:

---

Yes. Note the return type of `Parallel.Foreach` is a [`ParallelLoopResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopresult%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which contains information that can only be available once all of the operations have completed, such as `IsCompleted`:

> Gets whether the loop ran to completion, such that all iterations of the loop were executed and the loop didn't receive a request to end prematurely.

`ParallelLoopResult` is a `struct` - and so whatever value is returned from `Parallel.ForEach` cannot be altered after the return from that method.

Comment: Hmm... isn't that sort of a bad argument? Tasks also have an `isCompleted` property, which you can use to poll them, exactly because they aren't blocking. Though yes, the description of the property makes it pretty clear in this case.

Comment: @Tobberoth - I was trying (and failing) to find anywhere in the MSDN library that explicitly stated that all loops would have been completed - but I was unable to do so. So I went with a slightly sideways way to try to demonstrate that the loop must be complete by the time the result is returned. And unlike a `Task`, given that `ParallelLoopResult` is a `struct`, its values must have been set (and can never be reset) once it has been returned.